# Log fs syscalls Mac

Tags: macos, logging, filesystems, system-calls

Is a programmatically solution to log every filesysten syscalls on Mac ?
I already do it on Linux with loggedfs, but this solution doesn't work on Mac

I'm focusing open syscall in /Users/$USER